# Ansible modules copy/template errors for Linux 5 hosts using python26 ,python binding libselinux-python needed

Tags: linux, selinux, ansible

We have some 50 odd linux 5 hosts, and to manage that we use ansible.

Problem  :- Ansible modules copy/template errors for Linux 5 hosts using python26 ,python binding libselinux-python needed

Actual error :- 
fatal : FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Aborting, target uses selinux but python bindings (libselinux-python) aren't installed!"}

Environment:-

```
Ansible Master node : - EL7
Selinux enabled
libselinux-python : installed libselinux-python.x86_64 0:2.5-14.1.el7

Node :- EL 5
Selinux enabled
Using ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python26
libselinux-python : installed libselinux-python-1.33.4-5.7.el5.x86_64
```

Description:-

I see the problem

With default Python ...

```
selinux]# python
Python 2.4.3 (#1, May 5 2011, 15:12:27)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

import selinux
selinux.is_selinux_enabled()
1
```

And with python26

```
[root@dev-bozo21 selinux]# python26
Python 2.6.8 (unknown, Nov 7 2012, 14:47:45)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

import selinux
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named selinux
```

I tried copying

"/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/selinux to /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/selinux ( this was empty earlier)"

it throws this error

```
python26
Python 2.6.8 (unknown, Nov 7 2012, 14:47:45)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

import selinux
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/selinux/init.py", line 5, in 
import _selinux
ImportError: /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/selinux/_selinux.so: undefined symbol: Py_InitModule4
```

And when copying

"/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/selinux/init.py" ( from different centos 7 node) to /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/selinux/

I get below error

```
python2.6
Python 2.6.8 (unknown, Nov 7 2012, 14:47:45)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

import selinux
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/selinux/init.py", line 26, in 
_selinux = swig_import_helper()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/selinux/init.py", line 22, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_selinux', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/selinux/_selinux.so)
```

Any solution for this problem ?

Comment: I voted - 1 for the question having an error in English suggesting a solution that the OP overlooked.

Comment: Thats pretty harsh :)

Comment: Not harsh; pragmatic. It gave you the solution, and you acknowledged you saw the solution. This question isn't about ansible failing. It's about the python version on your node missing libraries/functions.

Answer (score 2):

I literally ran into this problem on a few hosts in my infrastructure today.

The solution is to do what the error says. Install the `libselinux-python` package. Or you could disable selinux on the target host(s).

From the [Ansible website](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/intro_installation.html):

> If you have SELinux enabled on remote nodes, you will also want to
>   install libselinux-python on them before using any copy/file/template
>   related functions in Ansible. You can of course still use the yum
>   module in Ansible to install this package on remote systems that do
>   not have it.

Comment: I do have libselinux-python installed in the node , But looks like it is bound with python2.4 , selinux module doesnt seem be there for python26.

Comment: And disabling SELINUX is not something we are looking into currently.

Comment: @PrakashSharma: Different versions of python require different versions of libraries. Install `libselinux-python` for python 2.6.

Comment: I thought for that , but couldn't find anything for python26 . On Linux 5 , I see this is the only package available libselinux-python-1.33.4-5.7.el5. No later version from that.

Comment: @PrakashSharma: You could search for the necessary package in an archived EPEL. Take a look at this link: https://www.ansible.com/blog/using-ansible-to-manage-rhel-5-yesterday-today-and-tomorrow

Comment: Exactly that I am using .. But not all modules work with  libselinux-python not available for python26. I will keep looking.

Comment: Copying modules/libraries for one definitive version of python into the folders of another version is **not** exactly best practice. I see two possible solutions; find what provides the libselinux-python files necessary for python2.6, or find another way to do this (without ansible?) With EL5 you are going to find limited support with modern orchestration tools like Ansible.

Answer (score 1):

I simply run this and it solved my problem

```
yum install libselinux-python3
```

Answer (score 1):

As already said the solution is install libselinux-python3.  To be more exact though libselinux-python3 needs to be installed on each host machine, not the ansible server.

To ensure that the library was installed on every host I added an extra line to install libselinux-python3 before I run any of the modules dependent on it.

```
- name: install python selinux library required by future ansible modules
  become: true
  yum:
    name: libselinux-python3
    state: present
    update_cache: true
```

this fixed my later commands that were previously failing.